# Tearing my hair out - ASP.Net AJAX AutoComplete not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, autocomplete

Hope someone can help with this.  I've been up and down the web and through this site looking for an answer, but still can't get the Autocomplete AJAX control to work.  I've gone from trying to include it in an existing site to stripping it right back to a very basic form and it's still not functioning.  I'm having a little more luck using Page Methods rather than a local webservice, so here is my code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="droptest.aspx.cs" Inherits="droptest" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
            MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="getResults" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox1">
        </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class droptest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string[] getResults(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        string[] test = new string[5] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        return test;
    }
}
```

Tried to keep things as simple as possible, but all I get is either the autocomplete dropdown with the source of the page (starting with the `<! doctype...`) letter by letter, or in IE7 it just says "UNDEFINED" all the way down the list.

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2008 at the moment, this is running on Localhost.  I think I've exhausted all the "Try this..." options I can find, everything from adding in [ScriptMethod] to changing things in Web.Config.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code?

Only other thing that *may* be having an effect is in Global.asax I do a Context.RewritePath to rewrite URLs - does this have any effect on AJAX?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, something I've added in from these suggestions has worked!!!  Still have a problem though, it works in a standalone project but adding it back into the existing project and it's not working again.  So thanks for the help so far, I have a working example, just have to figure out what is killing it inside the other project now.

Comment: I've narrowed it down - its the Context.Rewrite in Global.asax that is causing the problem.  Question now is how I get around that...

Comment: I've added in some code to Global.asax which only rewrites the url if it has a file extension other than .axd.  So if it has .aspx or something else according to the re-write rules it gets checked and re-written, if not it gets left alone.

Thanks to everyone for the help anyway...

Answer (score 6):

You also need to include your page name as the servicePath, I think.

```
    <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
            MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="getResults" ServicePath="droptest.aspx" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: This is using PageMthods, so I thought you had to exclude the ServicePath, that's only for WebServices - tried it and still get the problem

Comment: I use page methods as well, and needed the service path.  Did you have the service path, the method defined as static, and the ScriptMethod attribute defined all at the same time?  That autocomplete control is pretty particular.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ServicePath to the cc1:AutoCompleteExtender with the path to the web service.

Comment: This is using PageMethods, so I thought you had to exclude the ServicePath, that's only for WebServices - tried it and still get the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public string[] getResults(string prefixText, int count)
{
```

be sure to include the ScriptMethod attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method `static`:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] getResults(string prefixText, int count)
{
        string[] test = new string[5] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        return test;
}
```

#### Update:

A shot in the dark... try moving the `ScriptManager` above the textbox. Also, I would set the `ServicePath` to "`~/`" simply because you mention the URL rewrites.

Comment: Tried that too - still just getting the Doctype and the rest of the sourcecode letter by letter in the results...
I have ajax UpdatePanels working elsewhere on the site so I know that is ok, it's just this thing from the Toolkit

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the `WebMethod` and see if it gets hit

Comment: When I was trying a local webservice instead of PageMethods I couldn't get them to fire either, even testing the .asmx with the Invoke button just hung the browser - is it possible there is a bigger issue with permissions or something on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 5.1, try to temporarily remove .* from the application setting.  This wildcard setting prevents AJAX like control to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my project use rewrite rule to remove the extension aspx. I thing the problem is that. I comment the rewrite rule in web.config. Then clear solution. Rebuild it. Clear all history in firefox / chrome (what you use). Then Ctrl+F5 or F5. Autocomplete show correctly.