# ASP.Net AJAX Autocomplete Not Working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I've looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306605/tearing-my-hair-out-asp-net-ajax-autocomplete-not-working) and I've tried all the suggestions there, but my Asp.Net AJAX Autocomplete still isn't working.

I have a test project with only a label, text box an the auto-completer:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:Label ID="FieldLabel" Text="Label:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender 
    ID="Autocompleter" 
    TargetControlID="InputField" 
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
    ServicePath="~/TestWebService.asmx" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    CompletionInterval="1000" 
    runat="server">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

I don't have any code-behind on the aspx page.  In TestWebService.asmx.cs, I have:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompetionList(string prefixText, int count)
{
    string[] results = { "test", "test", "test" };
    return results;
}
```

In theory, my textbox should have an autocomplete dropdown containing 3 instances of the word "test".  In practice, I can type anything I want into the textbox and nothing happens.  Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The same code i tried but not working for me. any other settings need  to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I misspelled the name of the WebMethod.  If you notice, its "GetCompetionList", not "GetCompletionList".

Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you web service method is missing an argument. Also make sure that you have set the correct styles for your autocompletion "drop-down". In other words, compare your code to [the reference](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx).

Comment: The real problem is that I can't spell.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you should to use

the word (static) after Public in your code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]

public static string[] GetCompetionList(string prefixText, int count)

{
  string[] results = { "test", "test", "test" };


   return results;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similiar issue and that was resolved by deleting these lines in web.config file.

```
<rules>
        <rule name="san aspx">
          <!--Removes the .aspx extension for all pages.-->
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />     
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
```